# How to update weather result on select option value change in ajax post method?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get weather result on select value change, I tried to many posts like : [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882139/update-span-value-on-select-option-change)
and some more. but couldn't make it work.

I know it seems easy, but I couldnt get over it, I get this error but code works fine if I dont use select box.

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp64\www\test\modules\weather.php
> on line 10

I want to update this div with two fields in it `$image` and `$dayTime` value:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <span id="wthr" class="float-md-left">
    <img src="<?php echo $image[1]; ?>" width="20" height="20"/>
    <?php echo $dayTime[1]; ?>
  </span>
</div>
```

Codes in index.php Cities :

```
$cities = array('adana' => 'ADANA', 'adiyaman' => 'ADIYAMAN', 'afyon' => 'AFYON',
    'agri' => 'AĞRI', 'aksaray' => 'AKSARAY', 'amasya' => 'AMASYA', 'ankara' => 'ANKARA',
    'antalya' => 'ANTALYA', 'ardahan' => 'ARDAHAN', 'artvin' => 'ARTVİN', 'aydin' => 'AYDIN'
    );

<div class="col-md-6">
    <span class="float-md-right">
        <select name="city" class="weather" id="city">
        <?php foreach($cities as $key => $value){
        echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
        </select>
    </span>
</div>
```

Ajax post :

```
$('#city').change(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    $.post('modules/weather.php', { selected: $('#city').val() },
        function(data) {
            $('#wthr').html(data);
        }
    );            
});
```

And weather.php which is in another folder **/modules/weather.php**

```
$city = $_GET['city'];
$data = [];

$url="http://www.mynet.com/havadurumu/asya/turkiye/".$city;
$source = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match('@<p class="hvPboxMiddle">(.*?)<\/p>@si',$source,$result);
preg_match('@<span class="hvDay">(.*?)<\/span>@si',$result[1],$day);
preg_match('@<span class="hvMood">(.*?)<\/span>@si',$result[1],$situation);
preg_match('@<span class="hvDeg1">(.*?)<\/span>@si',$result[1],$dayTime);
preg_match('@<span class="hvDeg2">(.*?)<\/span>@si',$result[1],$nightTime);
preg_match('@<img src="(.*?)" alt="(.*?)" />@si',$result[1],$image);

$data[] = $image[1] . $dayTime[1];
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: You're making a POST request but using $_GET and sending `selected` as the parameter but using `city`?

Comment: I was using POST but tried GET is well and forgot to change back it didnt make difference,  thought **selected** posts value to other page no ?

Comment: I would recommend not using regular expressions for HTML scraping. Perhaps use a method mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813273/web-scraping-in-php If you want to use regex, make sure to test your regex code using something like https://regex101.com/

Comment: You may want to use `https://www.mynet.com/havadurumu/asya/turkiye/` in your intial request, checking the insecure `http://` URL, yields a `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved permanently`

Comment: @segFault Mynet response in both but I will change it once I make code work. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your implementation.

1. You are using Regular Expressions for HTML scraping; it may work with HTML cases you're actually seeing, but it may break for HTML code that you haven't seen yet. A use of an HTML scraper is suggested but this code works for now.
2. You are getting this error on `weather.php` on line 10, because there is no data, because there is no `city` in `$_GET` nor `$_POST` array data, because you're actually passing a POST parameter with the name of `selected` rather than `city` name that your PHP fetch script is using.
3. You are trying to present/echo PHP data/variables when you are doing an AJAX request fetching some JSON data from the server; you either fetch JSON and update selected HTML elements with that specific data, or just return HTML code to replace the HTML code inside the `#wthr` element.

### Fully working code

#### `index.php`

```php
<?php

$cities = array(
  'adana' => 'ADANA',
  'adiyaman' => 'ADIYAMAN',
  'afyon' => 'AFYON',
  'agri' => 'AĞRI',
  'aksaray' => 'AKSARAY',
  'amasya' => 'AMASYA',
  'ankara' => 'ANKARA',
  'antalya' => 'ANTALYA',
  'ardahan' => 'ARDAHAN',
  'artvin' => 'ARTVİN',
  'aydin' => 'AYDIN'
);

?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PHP Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <span class="float-md-right">
        <select name="city" class="weather" id="city">
        <?php foreach ($cities as $key => $value): ?>
          <option value="<?= $key ?>"><?= $value ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
      </span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <span id="wthr" class="float-md-left">
      <!--
        We don't include any elements here,
        because we're going to return
        the entire HTML code from the server.

        <img src="<?= $image[1] ?>" width="20" height="20"/>
        <?= $dayTime[1] ?>

      -->
      </span>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $('#city').change(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.post(
          'weather.php',
          {
            // Here we pass the correct/expected parameter name
            // to the server script which is `city`
            city: $('#city').val()
          },
          function (data) {
            // We get raw HTML code from the server,
            // so we can update the entire element HTML code.
            $('#wthr').html(data);
          }
        );            
      });

      $(function () {
        // Update with the first selected city on page initial load.
        $('#city').trigger('change');
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### `weather.php`

```php
<?php

$city = $_POST['city'];
$data = [];

$url="http://www.mynet.com/havadurumu/asya/turkiye/".$city;
$source = file_get_contents($url);



preg_match('@<p class="hvPboxMiddle">(.*?)<\/p>@si', $source, $result);
preg_match('@<span class="hvDay">(.*?)<\/span>@si', $result[1], $day);
preg_match('@<span class="hvMood">(.*?)<\/span>@si', $result[1], $situation);
preg_match('@<span class="hvDeg1">(.*?)<\/span>@si', $result[1], $dayTime);
preg_match('@<span class="hvDeg2">(.*?)<\/span>@si', $result[1], $nightTime);
preg_match('@<img src="(.*?)" alt="(.*?)" />@si', $result[1], $image);

// $data[] = $image[1] . $dayTime[1];
// echo json_encode($data);

// Here we return the first element of the $image array
// that is a ready made HTML IMG element and we concatenate the $dayTime[1]
// which by the way is just retrieving the temperature in celcius degrees
// (class="hvDeg1" seems incorect for a $dayTime value).

die($image[0]."<span>{$dayTime[1]}</span>");
```

### Fully working online replit

You can check the fully working code onto this Replit: https://replit.com/@ChristosLytras/CuddlyRaggedTransfer#index.php

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanition, I dont use this as it is in question, This was needed for something else and I didnt want to ask a new question bcoz its almost same. I am getting data from mynet and inserting it in to database and listing from database. I use simple DOM. Thank you again I will forward award in 13 hours.